# How to detect certain color of circle, in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

If I were to create a circle, and have it iterate colors with the click of a button as shown in code below:

```
color_iteration1 = itertools.cycle(('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow'))
color_iteration2 = itertools.cycle(('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red',  'yellow'))
color_iteration3 = itertools.cycle(('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow'))
color_iteration4 = itertools.cycle(('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow'))

def callback1():
mcircle1 = mycanvas.create_oval(10,620,86,675, outline='#000000',fill=next(color_iteration1))

def callback2():
mcircle2 = mycanvas.create_oval(100,620,176,675, outline='#000000',fill = next(color_iteration2))

def callback3():
mcircle3 = mycanvas.create_oval(190,620,266,675, outline='#000000',fill = next(color_iteration3))

def callback4():
mcircle4 = mycanvas.create_oval(280,620,356,675, outline='#000000',fill = next(color_iteration4))

B1 = Button(root,text='B1',command =callback1)
B2 = Button(root,text='B2',command =callback2)
B3 = Button(root,text='B3',command =callback3)
B4 = Button(root,text='B4',command =callback4)
```

How would I store whatever color the circle was at any given time, that was contained in the iterate list. For example if I pressed a button twice and landed on green, how could I say that mcircle is now green and store it as a variable?

Oh and also if it were easier, is there a method for going through each pixel of the circle, and if it detects a certain RGB value, it sends off a flag to turn a certain variable equal to whatever color the RGB value was within the circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the reference for the item (the return value of `create_oval`), you can get option of the item using [`Canvas.itemcget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemcget-method):

```
oval = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 20, 20, fill='red')
canvas.itemcget(oval, 'fill')  # => Returns 'red'
```